# Change log level dynamically from asyncio outside module

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7, python-multiprocessing

I need to dynamically change log level without reloading any modules. For this, I am using a combination of asyncio and multiprocessing (both for the bigger program that I am writing).

**log_config.py**

```
def setupLogging(log_level=None): # load custom logger
    with open(os.path.join(LOG_PATH,'log_config.yaml'), 'rt') as file_:
        config = yaml.safe_load(file_.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
        logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime

    if not log_level:
        log_level = 'preview'
    
    return logging.getLogger(log_level)

logger=setupLogging() # global var that needs dynamic updation
async def logger_changes(): # socket listener that changes the logger object
    global logger
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('localhost', 9999))
    sock.listen()
    sock.setblocking(0)
    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            conn.send(data)
            logger = setupLogging(data.decode('utf8'))
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def logger_handler():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(logger_changes())
    await t1

def start_logger():
    start_func = asyncio.run(logger_handler())

pLOGGER = Process(name="__startLOGGER__", target=start_logger, daemon=False)
pLOGGER.start()
```

**Main Functionality**

```
import log_config
logger=log_config.logger

async def core_func():
    for i in range(10):
        logger.debug("sample debug log")
        logger.info("sample info log")
        logger.warning("Watch out!")
        logger.error("Heading for trouble!")
        logger.critical("Seriously, do something!")
        print("#"*80)

        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def core_func_parent():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(core_func())
    await t1

def core_func_handler():
    start_func = asyncio.run(core_func_parent())

if __name__=='__main__':
    pMODULE = Process(name="__startMODULE__", target=core_func_handler, daemon=False)
    pMODULE.start()
```

**Trigger Log Level Change**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(('localhost', 9999))
request = "test"

try:
    server.send(request.encode('utf8'))
    response = server.recv(255).decode('utf8')
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    server.close()
```

**Steps**

1. Run main functionality python script. Automatically invoked log_config from inside, starts the socket listener and instantiates the `logger` object
2. Run trigger log level change that sends a message to the web socket with the updated `logger` setting

**Challenge**

Once I run step 1, the logging level is `INFO` (which is exactly what I want)

But once I run step 2, I am expecting the logging level to change to `DEBUG` which is not happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't make use of any asyncio functionality. For instance, `logger_changes` doesn't await anything, so it works just like an ordinary sync function. Also, it swallows all exceptions without printing anything, so you don't see if anything goes wrong. In asyncio you should use [`asyncio.start_server()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) to listen to a port and [`asyncio.open_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) to connect to a server.

Comment: Creating a task and immediately awaiting it makes no sense, you should just await the coroutine directly. Most importantly, if you use asyncio, your whole program should be running inside of the asyncio event loop - you cannot just call `asyncio.run()` and be done with it.

Comment: @user4815162342 the `asyncio.start_server()` is definitely interesting and I need to take a look. The code provided here is MCVE, lot of logic in the middle has been omitted for brevity. Is there anyway using the same scheme I can achieve dynamic logger changes?

Comment: I support the desire to make an MCVE minimal, but it should also be correct. In this case omitting exception handling is a show-stopper because it sweeps exceptions under the rug. It is hard to tell if your approach would work for dynamic logger changes because you didn't describe the rest of your program - is it async, synchronous/threadaed, or just synchronous. It looks like you want the server to run "in the background", in which case the rest of your program should run inside the asyncio event loop as well. Neither your code nor your comment makes it clear whether that is the case.